# Execute SQL Server jobs using React JS

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

Currently we have SSIS packages placed in a shared folder and are called using PowerShell script which is called by a bat script using jsf. We’re planning to move our front end from jsf to React JS and database from Oracle to SQL Server. I want to know if we can call jobs created in SQL server agent, which will run packages deployed in catalog server, using React JS so that we can remove PowerShell and bat script dependency. Would be a great help if you guys can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a SQL Agent job that runs the package, you can start the job by calling proc [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in msdb.

Comment: Do you want web browsers directly accessing your SQL Server? Seems like you need a web API method somewhere that can call sp_start_job on behalf of the users.

Comment: Thanks Dan and AlwaysLearning for the idea. Can’t we call sp_start_job directly using reactjs without having any API?